# C++ int assignment not working

Tags: c++

I've having an issue with my code. It complies fine, but my int week and int days aren't updating properly, and returning to the value 0 in which they were initially assigned. I'm a very novice programmer, and this code is just a snippet of another I'm trying to write. Thanks for any and all help? EDIT: Also, I had to return days by rewriting the basic_order int, it's super inefficent, but I don't know how to do it any other way.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int BasicMakespan(int &basic_order)

{
    int shirts_left, days, weeks;
    days = 0;
    weeks = 0;
    shirts_left = basic_order - 1000;
    while (shirts_left >= 0)
    {
        shirts_left = shirts_left - 1000;
        days = days + 1;
        if (days == 6)
        {
            days = 0;
            weeks = weeks + 1;
        }
    }
    basic_order = weeks;
    return days;
}

int main ()
{
    int basic_order;
    cin >> basic_order;
    BasicMakespan ( basic_order );
    cout << BasicMakespan << " " << basic_order << endl;
}
```

Comment: how about you `cout` the value of `days` each time you change it. That should highlight any issues

Comment: Input is a shirt order in number of shirts (number will be in thousands) and output is weeks it takes to complete order and days into next week the productions goes. Can only produce 6 out of 7 days per week.

Comment: Did you *intend* to output the address of a function in your final `cout` insertion.?

Comment: Should it be  "if (days == 7)"?

Comment: @philipwhite I also thought of that, but it looks like the company that makes the shirts closes on sundays :-)

Comment: "Input is a shirt order in number of shirts (number will be in thousands) and output is weeks it takes to complete order and days into next week the productions goes. Can only produce 6 out of 7 days per week" - That *almost* makes sense. You would be better off just calculating the number of days it takes to fill an order and let the *caller* decide how many work-weeks are required. This function shouldn't have to.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, that's great; please post the update as an answer. Don't edit your question to add the answer; this box is for questions :)

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, it's really confusing and I wish I could explain it better, but like I said, it's sorta a snippet of a much larger program, I just need these to values to continue coding my larger program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant to write this:

```
int main ()
{
    int basic_order;
    cin >> basic_order;
    int result = BasicMakespan ( basic_order );
    cout << result << " " << basic_order << endl;
}
```

? Because your code is currently printing the address of `BasicMakespan`, not the result it returns.